# Trying to delete an item from arrays of objects in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components, javascript-objects

I'm learning React. I'm trying to build a simple todo app on my own to learn & practice with the library. I have passed a list of tasks in the **parent component** & passed them to the **child component** as props. I was also able to output it in the child component using the `map()` method. However, I have no idea how to delete an item. I have tried searching online, but I'm unable to adapt their solutions to my use case.

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles/components/App.css';
import Todos from './components/Todos'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      { task: 'Study React', id: 1 },
      { task: 'Build something with it',  id: 2 },
      { task: 'Apply for jobs', id: 3 },
    ],
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Todos todos={this.state.todos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../styles/components/Todos.css'

class Todos extends Component {
    render() {
        let { todos } = this.props;

        let todoList = todos.map(( todo => {
            return (
                <div className="todos" key={todo.id}>
                    <div>{ todo.task }</div>
                </div>
            )
        }));
        return (
            <div onClick={this.deleteTask}>{ todoList }</div>
        )
      
    }
    deleteTask() {
        // checks if method is working
       console.log('working');
       // code to delete 
    }
}

export default Todos
```

Comment: you can use `.filter()` to remove items that you don't want

Comment: Why don't you try to put the delete event in the App component ? Then use props give Todos component trigger it.

Comment: @GQSM I am a noob in React. I have no idea how to accomplish these solution. Do you mind providing me the answer using my code sample & explainining a bit the solution?

Comment: Okay! Wait for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles/components/App.css';
import Todos from './components/Todos'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      { task: 'Study React', id: 1 },
      { task: 'Build something with it',  id: 2 },
      { task: 'Apply for jobs', id: 3 },
    ],
  };

  // Event and data put in same Component.
  deleteTodo(id) {
    let workTodos = [...this.state.todos];
    const deleteIndex = workTodos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === id);
    workTodos.splice(deleteIndex, 1);
    this.setState({
      todos: [...workTodos]
    })
  }

  render(){
    // Use props give Todos Component the data and events to render dom
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Todos
            todos={this.state.todos}
            deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo.bind(this)}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../styles/components/Todos.css'

class Todos extends Component {
  render() {
    // Receiving events and data form props
    let { todos, deleteTodo } = this.props;

    // Click div trigger deleteTodo, It can execute deleteTodo in App component
    return todos.map(( todo => {
        return (
            <div
              className="todos"
              key={todo.id}
              onClick={() => { deleteTodo(todo.id) }}
            >
                <div>{ todo.task }</div>
            </div>
        )
    })); 
  }
}

export default Todos
```

Like a commit, put delete event in App component, Then use props trigger it in the Todos component, Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @CQSM thanks, but it throwing an syntax error in the deleleTodo() method...I removed the const keyword and eliminates that error, but I got workTodo is undefined

Comment: `filter` is easier than finding the index and then splicing out the object.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Sorry `const` is superfluous in Class Component, I edit answer.

Comment: @Andy But deleteEvent expect delete todo item

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Sorry! I did not notice before `splice` variable is wrong. 
I changed the code in answer.

Comment: Yeah, the error is in line 18, which variable should I be using? Man, I feel so fustrated and dumb learning React. It is insane that I have built apps with Vue & I am not able to figure this out by myself

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Just change `worktodo` to `worktodos` ! It is my wrong !

Comment: Okey done and the error is gone, but when I click on it I get: App.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: this.todos is not iterable

Comment: `const filteredTodos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);`, then just set the new state to the filtered array. @GQSM

Comment: @Andy This it a good idea ! I never thought about it this way.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Can you print workTodos to console ? I want check it value after delete.

Comment: The problem is with `let workTodos = [...this.todos];`. It should be `let workTodos = [...this.state.todos];`.

Comment: @Andy I use your solution, but now it maintains the item that I clicked and removed the rest of them...

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Please try again ! The result of `workTodos.splice(deleteIndex, 1);` don't give `workTodos`

Comment: @CQSM and Andy thanks a lot to both of you! Could you please include code comments to explain what is going on here? I need to understand

Comment: @ManuelAbascal I try to add comments, You can look it ! If you have any question, Please tell me.

Comment: @CQSM thanks for the answer! I keep learning, I am a bit discouraged at the moment. It is so hard to accomplish something with React jeez!